# Let $g(z) = 1/(1+e^{-z})$ be the logistic function. Show that $1-g(z)=g(-z)$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

I am having trouble with this problem. I am able to work it out to the point where I have either an extra $1$ or with $e^z$ and $e^{-z}$ and also the extra $1$

Let $g(z)= 1/ (1+e^{-z})$
Show that $1-g(z)=g(-z)$

from this I say
$1 - g(z) $        = $g(-z)$

$1 - (1/(1+e^{-z})) = 1/(1+e^z)$ ### this becomes a positive $z$

$1 - (1+e^{-z})^{-1} = (1+e^z)^-1$ ### we know that $1/x = x^{-1}$ property

$1 - (1+e^z) = (1+e^{-z})$   ### distribute negative

$1 - 1+e^z = 1+e^{-z}$   ###
$0 + e^z = 1 + e^{-z}$
and now I'm stuck

else

$1 - 1+e^z  = 1+e^{-z}$       ###

$0 + e^z = 1 + 1/e^z$

and I'm still stuck

Comment: Your question is rather hard to follow, as the mathematical formatting is somewhat lacking.  Please familiarize yourself with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and use that to format your question.

Comment: $$1-g(z)=1-\frac 1{1+e^{-z}}=\frac {e^{-z}}{1+e^{-z}}=\frac {e^{-z}}{1+e^{-z}}\cdot\frac{e^z}{e^z}=\frac 1{1+e^{z}}=\frac 1{1+e^{-(-z)}}=g(-z)\ .$$

Comment: That being said, your approach is flawed from the first step.  In your very first line (the one labeled "this becomes a positive z", you have assumed the thing that you are trying to prove.  If you are trying to prove a statement, it doesn't help to assume that statement from the start.

Answer (score 1):

$1-g(z)=1-\frac 1 {1+e^{-z}}=\frac {e^{-z}} {1+e^{-z}}$. Multiply numerator and denominator by $e^{z}$ to get $1-g(z)=\frac 1 {1+e^{z}}=g(-z)$.